# IGBinary errors

Tags: php, igbinary

I just replace serialized PHP with IGBinary .

I follow this steps:

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/phadej/igbinary
cd igbinary

phpize 
./configure CFLAGS="-O2 -g" –-enable-igbinary –-with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
make
make test
make install
```

But in the step : `make test`

I get stuck with:

```
ERROR: Cannot run tests without CLI sapi.
```

and this is probably is what is causing this other error:

in

http://censocanino.com/log.php

here I use a code to see if the session starts correctly.

and that brought a couple of errors:

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot find serialization handler 'igbinary' - session startup failed in /sites/censocanino.com/public/log.php on line 6
```

and

```
The current "session.save_path" is "/var/lib/php5".
Session file name: "sess_".
```

That error prove why  `phpmyadmin`  does't work.

http://censocanino.com/phpmyadmin/

What shows here is :

```
Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.
```

all that brought me to the IGBinary Error.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

You know that time when you haver 12 hors investigating why the code is not working and suddly you decide to type everything again .

well that happened to me , it seems was a typo erro.

may be was in `--enable-igbinary`  that the `--`  were different characters.

but thanks anyway